# Livepatch not working in 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, canonical-livepatch

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 especially to enable Livepatch. Unfortunately, I get the same error I had with Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable [key]
2019/10/22 17:20:20 error executing enable: Livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 19.10 is not supported. exiting.
```

Does anybody have any clue where the problem could come from?